Compactness of set of measurable functions between compact subspaces of real numbers
Let $X$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y$ be a convex and compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$. Consider $\mathcal{F}$ the set of all measurable functions from $X$ to $Y$. Can I find topologies under which $\mathcal{F}$ is compact as well?
I am in particular thinking about topologies of the weak type or metric or norm induced topologies. For instance p-norms seem to be interesting.

Cross-posted from MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4952820/compactness-of-set-of-all-measurable-functions

yes but it got closed there and answers are not allowed to be given


Do you assume compact to be Hausdorff? 2. You want elements of $\mathcal F$ to be functions, or $L^\infty$ classes?


Not necessarily but we can assume it if it will help us to make it compact.

So by classes you mean equivalence classes of functions that are equal a.e.? I think I  mean that the elements should be functions. But if it is better to assume that they are equivlanece classes then we may assume that for now but then they should rather be equivalence classes  from $Lp$ not $L^{\infty}$. At the moment I try to find just anything that would work and give me some intuition on how to approach this problem

@PietroMajer I would be very happy about any answer or insights!

(note that the $L_p$ classes  of functions in $\mathcal F$  are the same for all $0\le p\le \infty$, since you are assuming that the functions take values in  the compact $Y$).

@PietroMajer thank you for that comment, I was not aware of that.

@PietroMajer So do you think it is possible to find a topology in which that set of measurable functions is compact?

it is delicate, because  e.g. the product topology on $Y^X$ is compact, but  $\mathcal F\subset Y^X$ is only relatively compact, and not closed  (unless $X$ is a singleton), although sequentially closed.
The weak topology of  $L^\infty(X,\mathbb R^p)$  would make  $\mathcal F$ (quotiented by a.e.  equivalence)  again relatively compact, but not closed, unless $Y$ is also convex.

@PietroMajer in fact in my case $Y$ is convex. So what does that mean for the weak topology of $L^{\infty}$?

It means that  $L^\infty(X,Y)$ is a closed  subset of $L^\infty(X,\mathbb  R^p)$ , hence compact  because $Y$ is  also bounded.  I think in general the weak closure of   $L^\infty(X,Y)$ is $L^\infty(X,\overline {\text{co}}Y)$

@PietroMajer I’m pretty sure you need $X$ to be diffuse if you want the weak closure to be $L^\infty(X, \overline{\text{co}} Y)$, though of course this is automatic if we’re only dealing with the restriction of the Lebesgue measure. (Also, you probably meant weak$^\ast$ topology instead of weak topology?)

@guest1 I’m aware (though it has now been reopened). It’s simply standard practice to mention if posts are cross-posted between two sites so as to avoid people unnecessarily repeating things already done on the other site.

Yes, sorry, of course I meant w*. And yes, here X is a compact subset of R^n, with the Lebesgue measure

@PietroMajer so considering your previous comment all that you have just said for $L^{\infty}$ also holds equivalently for Lp spaces? And which measures are allowed for these Lp or $L^{\infty}$ spaces? Do probability measures work for this construction?

Yes,  if $X$ is a  finite measure space,  and $Y\subset \mathbb R^m$ is a compact convex set,  the  w* topology  of $L^p$ for $1<p\le\infty$  (of course $w=w^*$ for  $1<p<\infty$) induces  the same  compact topology on  $\mathcal F$ (after quotient by a.e. equivalence): all these topologies make $\mathcal F$ Hausdorff compact by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, and  are comparable  (since $X$ has finite measure the inclusion $L^\infty \to L^p$  is continuous   wrto these topologies ) .

@PietroMajer thank you again! But there are not restriction on $X$ regarding that it has to be finite or atomic/non-atomic?
Could we make $\mathcal{F}$ somehow also compact in the topology induced by the $Lp$ norm?

Also can anyone here judge whether the answer of Dieudonne is mathematically correct? I dont have the level to judge it and the user is completely new so it is hard to tell how reliabe the user is.

@guest1 The first paragraph of their answer is definitely correct. It’s basically the same thing as my comments (over at MSE) and Pietro’s comments above. The second paragraph doesn’t have any issue mathematically, but I’m not sure what the connection to your problem is, since Arzelà-Ascoli is about spaces of continuous functions, not measurable ones. I don’t know about Young measures, so I’m not qualified to judge the final two paragraphs.

Consider the quotient space $[\mathcal{F}]_\mu$ of $L^\infty(X,\mathbb{R}^p)$ modulo $\mu$-a.e. equivalence, where $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure on $X$. Endowed with the weak* topology $\sigma(L^\infty, L^1)$, $[\mathcal{F}]_\mu$ is compact by Banach-Alaoglu. This topology is metrizable if and only if $L^1(X,\mathbb{R}^p)$ is separable, which occurs precisely when $X$ is separable (with respect to the topology induced by $\mu$) and $p$ is finite.
The Arzelà-Ascoli theorem provides compactness in the uniform topology for equicontinuous subsets of $\mathcal{F}$. For compact metric spaces (which include compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$), the equicontinuity condition can be replaced by pointwise boundedness and equicontinuity at each point. This classical result extends to more general settings via the notion of total boundedness in uniform spaces.
Young measures offer a broader framework, embedding $\mathcal{F}$ into the space $\mathcal{Y}(X,Y)$ of measurable maps $\nu: X \to \mathcal{P}(Y)$, where $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ denotes probability measures on $Y$ with the weak* topology. $\mathcal{Y}(X,Y)$ is compact in the stable topology, which refines the topology of weak convergence of measure-valued maps.
Weak* convergence in $[\mathcal{F}]_\mu$ implies convergence in the Young measure sense, but not conversely. This asymmetry reflects the capacity of Young measures to capture fine oscillatory behavior. The stable topology on $\mathcal{Y}(X,Y)$ can be metrized via the Prokhorov-Lévy metric when $Y$ is separable. weak convergence for probability measures on Polish spaces.
